AOSP missing dependencies: android.hardware.radio-library.compat
I'm kinda new on this topic, and I need to add a new radio device/RIL but I've some errors while I'm trying to build saying that it miss some dependencies.
echo "module libril-lib missing dependencies:
android.hardware.radio-library.compat, android.hardware.radio.config-V1-ndk, android.hardware.radio.data-V1-ndk, android.hardware.radio.messaging-V1-ndk, android.hardware.radio.modem-V1-ndk, android.hardware.radio.network-V1-ndk, android.hardware.radio.sim-V1-ndk, android.hardware.radio.voice-V1-ndk"

I'm using the following Android.bp :
cc_library {
name: "libril-lib",
vendor: true,
cflags: \[
"-Wextra",
"-Wno-unused-parameter",
\],
srcs: \[
"RefRadioNetwork.cpp",
"ril.cpp",
"RilSapSocket.cpp",
"ril_config.cpp",
"ril_event.cpp",
"ril_service.cpp",
"sap_service.cpp",
\],
include_dirs: \[
"vendor/native_ril/include",
\],
shared_libs: \[
"android.hardware.radio-library.compat",
"android.hardware.radio.config-V1-ndk",
"android.hardware.radio.data-V1-ndk",
"android.hardware.radio.messaging-V1-ndk",
"android.hardware.radio.modem-V1-ndk",
"android.hardware.radio.network-V1-ndk",
"android.hardware.radio.sim-V1-ndk",
"android.hardware.radio.voice-V1-ndk",
"android.hardware.radio@1.0",
"android.hardware.radio@1.1",
"android.hardware.radio@1.2",
"android.hardware.radio@1.3",
"android.hardware.radio@1.4",
"android.hardware.radio@1.5",
"android.hardware.radio@1.6",
"android.hardware.radio.config@1.0",
"android.hardware.radio.config@1.1",
"android.hardware.radio.config@1.2",
"android.hardware.radio.config@1.3",
"android.hardware.radio.deprecated@1.0",
"libbase",
"libbinder_ndk",
"libcutils",
"libhardware_legacy",
"libhidlbase",
"liblog",
"librilutils",
"libutils",
\],
static_libs: \[
"libprotobuf-c-nano-enable_malloc",
\],
}

filegroup {
name: "libril-modem-lib-manifests",
srcs: \[
"android.hardware.radio@2.0.xml",
\]

I don't really understand where am I supposed to add these shared_libs : android.hardware.radio.*
in order to build.
Any ideas or tips in order to help me ?
